# Checking message automatically shown by JavaScript in the Web Browser

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net

I have a program that it automatically logs on a website, and there is the Feedback that was logged in, eg Hello, welcome back User blablabla, now when an error occurs, it shows a Feedback in the middle of the site over the program does not detects, soon after discovered that is a Feedback in js, the code I use to detect Feedback from logged into the site is :

```
            If Me.WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml.Contains("Hello, welcome back ") Then
            Me.boxdies.Items.Add("☑" + Me.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value + "Mês:" + "~~Logged")
            txtstatus.ForeColor = Color.Red
            txtstatus.Text = "Logged!"
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(0)
            Login.Stop()
```

and if you want the message javascript code that appears on the site, it is:

```
<p><script language="javascript:;" type="text/javascript">
            var nameShow = $('input[id=ControlGroupContact_PassengerInputViewPassengerView_TextBoxExceptionNotificationAllBlue]').val()
            var message = 'If your usual login does not work, please try using your CPF (only numbers, no hyphen or dots). If the problem persists contact the TudoAzul via telephone 4003-1141 or by email tudoazul@voeazul.com.br';

            document.write(message.replace("NAME_ALL_BLUE", "\"" + nameShow + "\""));
          </script>If your usual login does not work, please try using your CPF (only numbers, no hyphen or dots). If the problem persists contact the TudoAzul via telephone 4003-1141 or by email tudoazul@voeazul.com.br</p>
```

Comment: please people help me

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: the code I use to detect the message logged is Hello, welcome again is not javascript, now that the problem log is in javascript and my code can not detect it.

Comment: Link Javascript image: http://prntscr.com/bct2cn and Login image that is not in javascript, is on the site and can use InnerHtml: http://prntscr.com/bct2se

Comment: Bad news are WebBrowser control doesn't have a managed way to interact with javascript popup dialogs like those shown with `alert()`and `confirm()`
Good news are you can [tweak an extended version of WebBrowser](http://zerosandtheone.com/media/p/27.aspx) to detect when these dialogs show. This can be of help, depending on what you want to do.